# How to set versions in a non-standard maven reactor build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-delivery, versions-maven-plugin

For reasons beyond my control, we have to use a maven project setup where the topmost pom.xml is not actually the parent pom. Now we would like to create a jenkins deployment pipeline, which of course would deploy a unique version of the entire reactor to our nexus repository.

Our setup is like this:

```
root (no parent pom)
 +---- parent  (company-wide parent pom is somewhere else)
 +---- module1 (parent pom is ../parent/pom.xml)
 +---- module2 (parent pom is ../parent/pom.xml)
```

Now we have to:

- set the versions of root, parent, module1 and module2 to our unique build version
- set the parent versions of module1 and module2 to the same build version
- leave the version of the external parent pom intact

I see no parameters in [the `versions:set` mojo](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) that do this.
Calling `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.3` sets the version for the root pom only. The exact same call works perfectly in a traditional parent / child reactor build.

Is there any possible solution?

Note:
`versions:update-child-modules` is not an option, since we can't define a specific target version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed [on the mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.turbine.maven.user/130834) and reported ([MVERSIONS-131](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508022538/https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-131)) with the conclusion that this would best be handled through implementing support for wildcards:

```
mvn versions:set -DgroupId='*' -DartifactId='*' -DoldVersion='*' -DnewVersion=1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

This improvement is reported as [MVERSIONS-228](https://web.archive.org/web/20150514123925/http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-228); it doesn't appear to be implemented in the current (2.1) release of `versions-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems we are stuck with creating our own maven plugin

Comment: It looks like MVERSIONS-228 has been fixed ([r18605](https://fisheye.codehaus.org/changelog/mojo?cs=18605)), but a 2.2 release of the plugin hasn't been made yet.

Comment: Seems the issue just got dropped when codehaus was closing as it's nowhere to be found on the GH project page nor in Google

Comment: I believe the fix ([this commit](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/commit/c8aebf9456b646b9c9ccb415069a7fde6d9bbfae)) is included in 2.2, which has [now been released](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/releases/tag/versions-maven-plugin-2.2).